# Firefox won't start download

Tags: html, download, anchor

I have a very simple code in HTML.

```
<a href="test.msg" download>Link</a>
```

I just want to download that file - works fine with Chrome and Edge, but Firefox always throws a file not found error (and the file exists on the server). I'm running all browsers on the latest versions.

Is there any workaround for that?

Comment: kill the firefox process from task manager and try it.

Comment: was the first thing i tried.. i suppose it has something to do with the .msg file.. because with .pdf everything works just fine..